# Meaning of the integral $I(t)=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+} \int_0^t\frac{\phi(y)}{(\epsilon +iy)^n}dy$

Tags: improper-integrals, dirac-delta, cauchy-principal-value

I am trying to give a meaning to this integral

$$I(t)=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+} \int_0^t\frac{\phi(y)}{(\epsilon +iy)^n}\,dy$$

where, $n > 1$,  $\phi(y)$ is a complex function, infinitely differentiable, and $y\in \mathbb R$. I thought it might be related to derivatives of $\delta(y)$ distributions, but I am quite stuck with the calculation.

Comment: Setting $\epsilon$ to zero the integral becomes $\int\limits_0^t \phi(y)\, (i y)^{-n}\,dy=i^{-n} \mathcal{M}_y[\phi(y)\, (1-\theta (y-t))](1-n)$ where $\theta(x)$ is the Heaviside step function and $\mathcal{M}_x[f(x)](s)=\int\limits_0^\infty f(x)\, x^{s-1}\ dx$ is the Mellin transform of $f(x)$.

Comment: While this can be true, the problem is now shifted in understanding under which condition such a transformation is meaningful, and how to deal with the singularity. To me, it is more like a way to rewrite the problem, not a solution.

Comment: I think the fact that $I(t)$ is related to the Mellin transform gives some meaning, but I don't understand your concern about a singularity. You can read up on the Mellin tranform at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform and https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MellinTransform.html to understand the conditions under which it exists. I don't know what you mean when you say you're stuck with the calculation as you won't be able to derive any result until you define the function $\phi(y)$.

Comment: For the simple case $\phi(y)=1$ the integral becomes $I(t)=\int_0^t \frac{1}{(i\, y)^n}\,dy=\frac{t\, (i\, t)^{-n}}{1-n}$ which is valid for $\Re(n)<1$. You can use Wolfram alpha to explore the results for various definitions of $\phi(y)$ (e.g. see https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integrate%5BE%5E%28-y%29%2F%28I+y%29%5En%2C%7By%2C0%2Ct%7D%5D ).

Comment: Sure, but In this problem n > 1.  This is exactly the point, for n<1 everything is fine, but for n > 1 then at y=0 we have singularity that is why I can't just replace the $\epsilon=0$.
I should probably edit the problem and make it clearer, as I wrote  "n is a positive integer".

Comment: I edited the question to make it clear that the problem requires $n > 1$.